# MapboxGL with Webpack: "ReferenceError: e is not defined" (in vue-cli app)

Tags: npm, webpack, vue.js, mapbox-gl-js, vue-cli

I'm developing a `vue-cli 2.9.3` app with the `webpack` template. I have a component which uses MapboxGL, imported with `import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl;'`.

Everything works fine in dev using `npm run dev`.

I can build the project without issue with `npm run build`. However, I get the following error on the console when navigating to the component using MapboxGL:

```
ReferenceError: e is not defined
```

The DevTools from Firefox or Chrome are unable to make the link to the sourcemap (`.js.map`) files, so the error message is not very helpful.

I was able to make the bundle work by using `devtool: eval-source-map` instead of `devtool: source-map` in `./config/index.js`, but the bundle size becomes > 8Mb which is not acceptable and it is [not recommended in production](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#production).

I have also tried without sourcemaps but I got the same cryptic error.

How can I debug this error in the packaged bundle? I would like to at least be able to see where the error comes from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that it is a [known bug](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/4359#issuecomment-288001933) with MapboxGL and Webpack.

It can be solved by adding the following in `./build/webpack.prod.conf.js`:

```
module: {
     ...
     noParse: /(mapbox-gl)\.js$/,
     ...
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to solve it for 2.6.1, any other idea?